# Vue: Dynamic images within a v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a method in a v-for to determine what image to show.  I am getting an empty source when I go to inspect the element though. Is this not a valid way to handle image rendering?

```
<div v-for="unit in units">
   <img :src="getImageUnit(unit)/>
</div>


methods: {
     getImageUnit(unitType) {
         if (unitType == "single") {
             return '/images/single.png';
         } else {
             return '/images/double.png';
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: To use image URLs like that, your files would have to be in the `public` folder. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, using methods to render parts of your template is [highly inefficient](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

You should be using a computed property for this instead.

Assuming your image files are all in the [`public` folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder), try this

```js
computed: {
  unitsWithImages: ({ units }) => units.map(unit => ({
    unit,
    image: `${process.env.BASE_URL}images/${unit === "single" ? "single" : "double"}.png`
  }))
}
```

```html
<div v-for="unit in unitsWithImages">
  <p>{{ unit.unit }}</p>
  <img :src="unit.image" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation and for the links for further reading as well!